# Serve static files from dependency project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have three projects in my solution: WebProject_A, WebProject_B and DependencyProject.

Currently WebProject_A is serving static files from its `WebProject_A/wwwroot` folder. Some of these files should be available to both WebProject_A and WebProject_B and I'd like to move them to DependencyProject, which is a dependency* of both WebProject_A and WebProject_B.

How do I serve these static files from both A and B?

Final deployment will be to AKS.

[*]
I already have Blazor components in DependencyProject that are used in both A and B.

Answer (score 0):

To share static file, you can set the **UseStaticFiles()**:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                @"C:\***\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication1\wwwroot")),  //define the wwwroot location
        });
```

Then both projects can use the same wwwroot.